# Insert inside trigger not firing

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

Hi i have this simple trigger in oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OCAP_CREATE_NCRB
BEFORE INSERT
ON OCAP_TBLOCAP
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
       Defect_Type    varchar2(16);
       out_           varchar2(60);
BEGIN

  Select A.DEFECT_TYPE into Defect_Type from OCAP_TBLDEFECT A where A.DEFECT_ID = :NEW.DEFECT;

   IF Defect_Type = 'C' THEN
         --Create NCRB
         
      SP_INSERTTBLD1D2(23,LPAD(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,6,'0'),0,'0','0','035823','Draft',' ',' ',34,' ',0,461,0,0,'035105',trunc(sysdate),' ','A',Lpad(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,6,'0'),Lpad(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,6,'0'),trunc(sysdate),'A',:New.BATCH_NO,out_);
      --insert action
      SP_INSERTTBLFORMYACTION(Lpad(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,6,'0'), out_, Lpad(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,6,'0'), Lpad(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,'0'), 'Draft');
      
      --Insert other affected Lots
      insert into TBLD2LOT(NCRBSERIESNO,LOTNO,CREATEDBY,CREATEDDT,SEQNO) Select (out_), A.BATCH_NO,Lpad(:NEW.ISSUED_BY,6,'0'),sysdate,(TBLD2LOTSEQ.nextval) from OCAP_OTHERBATCH A where A.OCAP_ID = :NEW.OCAP_NO;

      
      --add NCRBSeries no. to table OCAP_TBLOCAP for referencing
     Update OCAP_TBLOCAP set NCRBSERIESNO = out_ where OCAP_NO = :NEW.OCAP_NO;
      
      --Insert ocap history 
      
   END IF;
   
   
END Ocap_Create_NCRB;
/
```

the first 2 stored procedure is working fine but the insert query is not .
I try to excute the insert query manunaly by replacing the `Out_` and the `:new.Ocap_no` it is working fine.
Is there something wrong in my query?

Hope someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it *isn't working*, then

```
from OCAP_OTHERBATCH A 
where A.OCAP_ID = :NEW.OCAP_NO;      --> this condition is never met
```

which means that no rows in `OCAP_OTHERBATCH` contain `OCAP_ID` value which is equal to `:NEW.OCAP_NO`.

Might be because of wrong letter case, `CHAR` datatype (right-padded with spaces up to column's full length), ... who knows. Without tables' description and sample data, it is difficult to guess.

Comment: It met the condition i try to select both table its has the data

Comment: As I said: provide test case - CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data. Procedures are irrelevant, you said that they executed successfully, so it is only INSERT's SELECT statement that fails.

Comment: o i see the problem now, table has no data yet after insert, but the the update query now is not working i try to un comment it